Rasperry Pi 5 GPIO pins unusable after server restart (rpi-lgpio package)
I am using the rpi-lgpio package.
I am using a FastAPI server through a virtual environment (.venv) on a Raspberry Pi 5 to turn on and turn off an LED via HTTP requests on from a flutter front-end.
Every time I restart the server, I get the following error and the pin seems to become unusable:
lgpio.error: 'GPIO not allocated'

When I switch to a different pin, it works until I restart the server again, even after rebooting the Raspberry Pi 5, it won't work. Below is my server side Python code. Please help me figure out what the problem is.
from typing import Union
from fastapi import FastAPI
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def read_root():
    await test()
    return {"Hello": "world"}

@app.get("/light-on")
async def light_on():
    GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)

    return {"light": "on"}

@app.get("/light-off")
async def light_off():
    GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)

   
    return {"light": "off"}`

I was expecting for the pins to simply become re-assignable and usable.

I mean, you're using async def light_on() - wouldn't it be advisable to call await GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)?

Ok, I can do that. Will it help with the problem I am facing?
